# terraform aws waf rules to allow access to path only for certain ip addreses

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf, web-application-firewall

I have 2 instances behind a load balancer and I need to secure access to the /admin.php script to be accessible to only certain IP addresses
Trying to do this with WAF but if there is a simpler way to do it with ALB that's also fine

The below code currently applies globally

```
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "allowed_ips" {
  name        = "allowed-ips"
  scope       = "REGIONAL"
  description = "IP set containing allowed IP addresses"
  ip_address_version = "IPV4"
  addresses = var.allowed_ip_addresses
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "web_acl" {
  name        = "example-web-acl"
  description = "Example Web ACL"
  scope       = "REGIONAL"
  default_action {
    block {}
  }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
      metric_name                = "web-acl-metric"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }

  rule {
    name     = "allow-only-from-allowed-ips"
    priority = 1
      

    statement {
      ip_set_reference_statement {
        arn = aws_wafv2_ip_set.allowed_ips.arn
      }
     

    }

    action {
      allow {}
    }
    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
      metric_name                = "allow-only-from-allowed-ips-metric"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }
  }
}



resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "load_balancer_acl_association" {
  resource_arn = aws_lb.external_alb.arn
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.web_acl.arn
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with ALB listener rules if the IP count is less to manage. You can mention up to 4 Source IPs as the total condition count is 5.

A rough sample of this is below:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "static" {
    listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.front_end.arn
    priority = 100
    action {
        type = "forward"
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.static.arn
    }
    condition {
        path_pattern {
            values = ["/admin.php"]
        }
    }
    condition {
        source_ip {
            values = ["1.2.3.4/32"]
        }
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "static" {
    listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.front_end.arn
    priority = 101
    action {
        type = "forward"
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.static.arn
    }

    condition {
        path_pattern {
            values = ["/admin.php"]
        }
    }

    action {
    type = "fixed-response"

    fixed_response {
      content_type = "text/plain"
      message_body = "Access Denies"
      status_code  = "403"
    }
}
```

Rule with priority **100** is to allow the list of IPs (i.e Forward to respective target group). Rule **101** will give back a `fixed-response` of 403 for everyone else.

[Terraform registry link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener_rule#source_ip)